# Setting template images when using an asset catalog in OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage, asset-catalog

I have an asset catalog that holds all the images I'm using in toolbar buttons and I'd like to set them all to be template images. As far as I know there's no way to set the image of a button to be a template image in IB, but if I create an image as follows

```
NSImage *buttonImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
[buttonImage setTemplate:YES];
```

then the image for 'imageName' becomes a template image throughout the app. Short of iterating every item in an asset catalog is there any way to do this?

I've tried setting the asset name in the catalog to *Template but that doesn't work. I've also tried renaming the backing images to include 'Template' but that also didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: I just ended up placing all the images that should be template images in a single asset catalog, then cycle through them and setTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

You're **supposed** to be able to do this in the xcassets file. There's a setting in the Utilities Panel -> Attributes inspector. It's called "Render As" and contains an option for "Template Image". Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug that prevents this from actually working, or the setting is misleading.

However, you actually **can** do this in IB.

1. Select your NSButton or NSToolbarItem
2. Show the Utilities Panel
3. Switch to the Identity Inspector (CMD+SHIFT+3)
4. Go to the User Defined Runtime Attributes section.
5. Add a boolean attribute called `image.template` and leave it set to true

If you have an alternateImage set for your NSButton you'll probably want to do the same thing for that property. So, add another attribute to the list called `alternateImage.template`